# Simple user metrics with Open Layers map

Tags: google-analytics, openlayers-3

I'm just getting started with Open Layers. I'm looking for simple map user metrics:

- Time spent on map
- Map loads
- Marker clicks

Comment: Can you rephrase this so it becomes an actual question (possibly including information about what you have tried so far etc. Judging by your tags my guess would be that you want to record map clicks in Googe Analytics ?).

Comment: I'm fairly sure OL doesn't provide anything like this out of the box, but it would be pretty easy to write custom code to fulfill your requirements (read: *"give it a try and ask on SO if you have some more specific questions"*)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for letting me know.